# Problems With Mounting UDF DVDs In Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, udf

When I'm trying to read DVDs (burned in Vista) in my Ubuntu Jaunty, it throws an alert

> Invalid mount option when attempting to mount the volume 'UDF Volume'.

I've installed packages `libudf0` and `udftools` but it doesn't help.
There is [a related thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=650697) in ubuntuformus, but there I couldn't find general solution.
And there is [an article](http://ascending.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/howto-read-vista-burnt-udf-dvds-on-ubuntu-linux/) about patching kernel to mount UDF partitions and but there were some kernel version restrictions and my kernel is `2.6.28-15-generic`.

How can I change 'mount options' for UDF or make my os support it ?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDF support should be built in; you can try mounting it on the commandline and checking for errors there or by running the "dmesg" command.

```
sudo mount -t udf -o ro /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

Unfortunately, that probably won't solve the problem.  Root cause of the thread you linked to is [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/213696).  The short version: your disc was burned with LiveFS, a Microsoft implementation of UDF 2.5 that isn't supported yet.

Workarounds for discs that you can't burn again in Vista:

- mount on a Windows XP/Vista/7 or Mac OSX computer and copy to your Linux system over a network.
- mount on a Windows XP/Vista/7 or Mac OSX computer and copy to a USB drive.
- make a WinXP/Vista/7 virtual machine, give it access to your CD drive, and copy the data from the VM to your Linux host.

If you can, burn the disc again using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or other software that allows you to **set the UDF version manually.  You need to set UDF to 2.01 or lower.**